# Modify Eclipse equals() method template

Tags: java, eclipse

The eclipse generated equals() method does not have { } for if structure. e.g

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    .........
    return true;
}
```

How can it be changed to generate code in following patter

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj){
        return true;
    }
    .........
    return true;
}
```

Comment: That isn't a Java standard indentation, and the default equals does that. Generally you override equals because you want to do something different then the default.

Comment: I'm sure you can configure your IDE such that the curly braces on an `if` statement are always enforced...

Comment: see also http://azagorneanu.blogspot.com.br/2011/08/how-to-generate-equals-hashcode.html (but I think @AVolpe solved this one)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the check `Use blocks in if statements` of the `Generate hashcode and equals` option to generate the brackets, like this:

[image: Check the use blocks in if statements]

And the code generated will look like:

[image]

Another option is use the `Save actions` feature, and add a `format sourcecode` action.

Cheers